# Issues appending a text file with new data and also updating the variable value

Tags: arrays, vb.net, structure, user-input, streamreader

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class HomeUtilityAudProgram
Private Structure HomeUtility
    Public kwCostDec As Decimal
    Public dailyHoursInt As Integer
    Public KwPowerInt As Integer
    Public waterGalCostDec As Decimal
    Public waterGalUsedInt As Integer
    Public decOperatingCost As Decimal
End Structure

Private objHomeUtility As HomeUtility

Public Property lstWords As Object

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TV.Click
    'Display TV
    lblMessage.Text = "TV"
End Sub

Private Sub decCostPerKw_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles decCostPerKw.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub intPowerPerKw_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles intPowerPerKw.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub intHoursPerDay_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles intHoursPerDay.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub DecBtnlCalcCost_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DecBtnCalcCost.Click
    Try
        'Array and variable declarations

        objHomeUtility.kwCostDec = Decimal.Parse(decCostPerKw.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
        objHomeUtility.dailyHoursInt = Integer.Parse(intHoursPerDay.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Number)
        objHomeUtility.waterGalCostDec = Decimal.Parse(decCostPerGal.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)
        objHomeUtility.waterGalUsedInt = Integer.Parse(intNumGalUsed.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.Number)

        Dim sr As New StreamReader("applianceWatt.txt")
        objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt = CInt(Val("")) '<< Add Val() to handle non-number strings
        Dim KwsPowerInt(-1) As Integer '<< add -1 inside brackets to initialise the array 
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Do Until sr.Peek = -1
            'grab one value at a time from text file
            objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt = CInt(Val(sr.ReadLine())) '<< Add Val() to handle non-number strings
            i += 1 '<< increment your counter
        Loop
        sr.Dispose() '<< close the file

        If objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt <= 6000 And objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt >= 10 Then

            objHomeUtility.decOperatingCost = objHomeUtility.kwCostDec * objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt * objHomeUtility.dailyHoursInt + objHomeUtility.waterGalCostDec * objHomeUtility.waterGalUsedInt
            lblMessage.Text &= " using " + objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt.ToString("G") + "Kw of power " + " for " + objHomeUtility.kwCostDec.ToString("C") + " an hour for " + objHomeUtility.dailyHoursInt.ToString("G") + " hours and " + objHomeUtility.waterGalCostDec.ToString("C") + " per gallon of water for " + objHomeUtility.waterGalUsedInt.ToString("G") + " gallons is " + objHomeUtility.decOperatingCost.ToString("C")

        Else
            lblMessage.Text = "Invalid wattage entered."

        End If

        Dim Result = MsgBox("Do you want to change the default wattage value?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Append Wattage")

        If Result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            intPowerPerKw.Visible = True

            objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt = File.CreateText.StreamReader("applianceWatt.txt")

            If objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt <= 6000 And objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt >= 10 Then

                objHomeUtility.decOperatingCost = objHomeUtility.kwCostDec * objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt * objHomeUtility.dailyHoursInt + objHomeUtility.waterGalCostDec * objHomeUtility.waterGalUsedInt
                lblMessage.Text &= " using " + objHomeUtility.KwPowerInt.ToString("G") + "Kw of power " + " for " + objHomeUtility.kwCostDec.ToString("C") + " an hour for " + objHomeUtility.dailyHoursInt.ToString("G") + " hours and " + objHomeUtility.waterGalCostDec.ToString("C") + " per gallon of water for " + objHomeUtility.waterGalUsedInt.ToString("G") + " gallons is " + objHomeUtility.decOperatingCost.ToString("C")

            Else
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid wattage entered."

            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error in quantity on hand or product cost", "Data Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Fridge_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Fridge.Click
    'Display Refrigerator
    lblMessage.Text = "Refrigerator"
End Sub

Private Sub Heater_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Heater.Click
    'Display Heater
    lblMessage.Text = "Heater"
End Sub

Private Sub Fan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Fan.Click
    'Display Fan
    lblMessage.Text = "Fan"
End Sub

Private Sub Dryer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Dryer.Click
    'Display Dryer
    lblMessage.Text = "Dryer"
End Sub

Private Sub Oven_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Oven.Click
    'Display Oven
    lblMessage.Text = "Oven"
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    decCostPerKw.Clear()
    intPowerPerKw.Clear()
    intHoursPerDay.Clear()
    decCostPerGal.Clear()
    intNumGalUsed.Clear()
    lblMessage.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    ' Close the form.
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Washer.Click
    'Display Washer
    lblMessage.Text = "Washer"
End Sub

Private Sub Label5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label5.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label6.Click

End Sub

Private Sub intNumGalUsed_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles intNumGalUsed.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

I had it working before but am tasked to add an array(s) or structure to the code which is why it is present. I have successfully added a structure and have accessed the text file and loaded it into the variable. My current issue is appending the value of the variable and updating the text file.

Comment: could you be more precise? you say you get an issue but what's the error code?

Comment: BC30574 and BC42104

Comment: and what it says! index out of range?

Comment: What are BC30574 and BC42104?

Comment: Those issues have cleared up and this is the only issue Error BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. homeUtliltyAudProgram C:\Users\etw11\OneDrive\Documents\POS408\homeUtliltyAudProgram\homeUtliltyAudProgram\homeUtilityAudProgram.vb

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type lstWords is meant to be. Try a `List(Of Integer)`:

```
Public lstWords As New List(Of Integer)
```

As for your text file reading, you're not making space for new entries:

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader("applianceWatt.txt")
Dim KwPowerInt As Integer = CInt(Val("")) '<< Add Val() to handle non-number strings
Dim KwsPowerInt(-1) As Integer '<< add -1 inside brackets to initialise the array 
Dim i As Integer = 0

Do Until sr.Peek = -1
  'grab one value at a time from text file
  KwPowerInt = CInt(Val(sr.ReadLine())) '<< Add Val() to handle non-number strings

  'Place value into array
  ReDim Preserve KwsPowerInt(i) '<< Add Redim Preserve to make space for the new result
  KwsPowerInt(i) = KwPowerInt

  'Output
  lstWords.Add(KwsPowerInt(i)) '<< add to List(Of Integer)
  i += 1 '<< increment your counter
Loop
sr.Dispose() '<< close the file
```

Comment: I substituted List(Of Integer) for lstWords and it is throwing error 30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

Comment: I have changed my code and instead of using arrays I have added added a structure and am successfully loading data from the file but am having an issue appending the data and the variable value. The code is above in initial post